# Why does "a=( * )" assign an array with one element for each filename in '*' instead of each word?

Tags: arrays, bash, glob

## Question Details

Suppose we have a directory with three files in it: `file_1`, `file_2`, and the very inconveniently named `file 3`. If my understanding of [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) is correct, the way `bash` interprets the string

```
echo *
```

is that it sees the (unquoted) `*`, and modifies the string so that it now reads

```
echo file_1 file_2 file 3
```

Then, since there are no more expansions to be performed, bash attempts to evaluate the string. In this case, it runs the command `echo`, passing to it *four* arguments: `file`, `3`, `file_1`, and `file_2`. In any case, the outputs are identical:

```sh
$ echo *
> file 3 file_1 file_2
$ echo file 3 file_1 file_2
> file 3 file_1 file_2
```

However, in other contexts, this doesn't seem to be what happens. For instance

```sh
$ arr1=( * )
$ arr2=( file 3 file_1 file_2 )
$ echo ${#arr1}
> 3
$ echo ${#arr2}
> 4
```

And yet, if shell expansion works the way it's described [in the `bash` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions), these ought to be identical.

Something similar happens in a `for` loop:

```sh
$ for f in *; do echo $f; done
> file 3
> file_1
> file_2
$ for f in file 3 file_1 file_2; do echo $f; done
> file
> 3
> file_1
> file_2
```

What am I missing? Does globbing not happen in these cases?

## Use case

I'm putting together a GitHub repo to centralize my dotfiles, following this suggestion from [MIT's Hacker Tools](https://hacker-tools.github.io/dotfiles/). The script I'm writing has two usages:

```
./install.sh DOTFILE [DOTFILE [DOTFILE ...]]
./install.sh -a
```

In the first case, each of the named dotfiles in `src/config` is symlinked to a corresponding dotfile in my home directory; in the second, the `-a` flag prompts the script to run as if I had entered every dotfile as an argument.

The solution I came up with was to run `ln -sih` in a `for` loop using one of two arrays: `$@` and `*`.<sup>1</sup> So, simply assign `FILES=( $@ )` or `FILES=( * )`, and then run `for f in $FILES`--except, it seems to me, `*` should break in this assignment if there's a filename with a space in it. Clearly `bash` is smarter than me, since it doesn't, but I don't understand why.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Obviously, you don't want the script itself to run through the loop, but that's easy enough to exclude with an `if [[ "$f" != "$0" ]]` clause.

Comment: Your understanding is not correct: Glob expansion does not result in a *string* at all; it results in a list of words. If expansion steps kept going back to a string representation, it would be next to impossible to handle untrusted data safely in bash, so it's very fortunate that it doesn't.

Comment: Note too that expansions happen in a very specific waterfall order; it's not a question of whether "any expansions remain" -- if you have a file created with `touch '$(rm -rf ~)'`, you don't want `echo *` to run that `$(...)` command.

Comment: Future tip: don't use `*` expansion. Use `find`. And work with null terminated strings and bash arrays. `IFS= readarray -d $'\0' arr < <(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0)
`

Comment: Can I ask what the advantage of null-terminated strings and bash arrays is over `*` expansion? Is it the danger @CharlesDuffy pointed out?

Comment: @jgaeb It guards against filenames with characters such as newlines in them. In UNIX/Linux, a filename can contain any character except the null character. And just to be clear, Kamil's example isn't creating "null-terminated" strings, it's creating a null-*delimited* output stream from `find`. I suppose you might call that six of one and half a dozen of the other, but the point is that the null is the separator between filenames, not merely an end-of-string indicator. Everything in-between two null characters (including `\n`, etc) is one filename.

Comment: Note that `FILES=( $@ )` is *exactly the same as* `FILES=( $* )`, and both are buggy. If you want to expand your argument list as an array, on element per item, that needs to be `"$@"`, with that exact quoting. (Also, all-caps names are in the namespace used for names meaningful to the shell and OS; better to use lowercase for your own shell and environment variable names -- see POSIX spec @ http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable will overwrite any like-named environment variable).

Comment: @KamilCuk, ...that said, can you please explain what you meant about `*` being dangerous? The `find` you suggest is certainly perfectly safe, results in an empty array if no files are found, and is going to include hidden files that `*` ignores, but I don't see any reason to advise "don't use the `*` expansion" as a general rule.

Comment: (I personally also consider `$'\0'` a bad practice -- it misleads people to think that bash can represent a literal NUL in a string, when in reality that expands to just `''` -- but certainly, reasonable people can differ there: Since `readarray -d` and `read -d` refer to *the first character* of the following string, and a 0-length string has a "first character" that is its NUL terminator, `$'\0'`, while misleading about how the syntax *works*, is explicit about what the syntax *means*).

Comment: @jgaeb, just to be sure you didn't take away a false impression -- `*` is perfectly safe with filenames containing newline literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`bash` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) you linked to:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion,
>   parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command
>   substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and
>   filename expansion.

Filename expansion happens *after* word splitting, and therefore the expanded filenames are not themselves subject to further word splitting.